# h2's are not in the same vertical line

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my two h2's in one vertical Line, so the first letter is on the same horizontal position. Here's a

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/279315/pexels-photo-279315.jpeg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#hdtxt {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#mail {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 700px;
}

#pwd {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login">
  <h1 id="hdtxt">LOGIN</h1>
  <h2 id="mail">Email:</h2>
  <h2 id="pwd">Password:</h2>
</div>
```

Well i found out that there isn't the problem because the text isn't centered here. But the problem isn't that it is not getting centered (it is on my private page). The problem is: When it is centered, it looks like this:

....Email:

Password:

(The ....'s are spaces)

Thanks to everyone who can help.

Comment: I am confused, you wish to have your text left aligned? but its not?

Comment: I am also confused. I have no idea what you are actually asking. But I will say: those ("Email:" and "Password:") aren't headings, so they shouldn't be `<h2>` ... if you're making them an h2 just because you want them larger, give them a `class` and use CSS instead.

Comment: Ah... you want the two things to have the same _horizontal_ position so they are left-aligned to the same vertical line, but more-or-less the whole thing is centered.  You may want to edit your question so that is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just erase the text-centering and use the same `padding-left` for both, preferrably a percentage value:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/279315/pexels-photo-279315.jpeg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#hdtxt {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#mail {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 40%;
  color: yellow;
}

#pwd {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 40%;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login">
  <h1 id="hdtxt">LOGIN</h1>
  <h2 id="mail">Email:</h2>
  <h2 id="pwd">Password:</h2>
</div>
```

Or you can put these two in a wrapper which you center....

Comment: Works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do that it will work perfectly I have tryed it :

copy it in:  https://codepen.io/abhilashn/pen/GraJyp and you will see the result :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login">
  <h1 id="hdtxt">LOGIN:</h1>
  <div id="email_password">
  <h2 id="mail">Email:</h2>
  <h2 id="pwd">Password:</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

and replace what you have written in the css under url by that :

```
#hdtxt {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
    margin-left:50%;
}
#mail,#pwd,#hdtxt
{
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
   padding-top: 50px;
}

#mail,#pwd  {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 700px;
}
#email_password
{
  margin-left:50%;
}
```

explication : 
It does not work for you because you put  `text-align: center;` for both `#mail` 
and `#pwd` and since the password is taller then email so you found this result .

```
margin-left:50%; make the element in the center horizontally.

margin-top:50%; make the element in the center vertically.
```

if you want just to center the login you have to omit :
    #email_password
    {
      margin-left:50%;
    }

Best practice :

if you want to do the same thing for your different element just do that :

```
elemt1,element2,...
{style}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Centering a block can be done by giving the block a width, then using "auto" margins.**

As I mentioned in my comment, I don't think these are headings, so I made them divs. As Johannes mentioned, you can put these in a wrapper, and center the wrapper.

What I do here is make this the "login section" a `<section>` with the id of "login".  This is the piece that has the background picture.

Inside that are the login fields, which is the wrapper block, and that is centered using the `width: 15ex` and `margin: 0 auto` rules -- no top or bottom margin, auto left and right margins, and you can pick an appropriate width yourself.
I also gave it a background color just so it's more visible what's going on here; you wouldn't do that for your actual site.

These also share most of the same style, so I eliminated the repeated `font-family` etc. on all the pieces and put those on the login-fields block (div).

The `<h1>` heading within the login section is different so it gets *just the differences* ... it doesn't need the font family repeated.  Since we are talking about the h1 that is in the login section, I used that as the CSS selector `#login h1 {`.

With these changes, none of the pieces need their own specific `id`s, so I removed the `id="hdtxt"` as well as `="mail"` and `="pwd"`.  You *might* need to keep the ids if your javascript is going to manipulate those elements directly.

If I were making this, most likely the words "Email:" and "Password" are `<label>`s that will go along with `<input>` controls.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#login {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/279315/pexels-photo-279315.jpeg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.login-fields {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 15ex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
#login h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="login">
  <div class="login-fields">
    <h1>LOGIN</h1>
    <div>Email:</div>
    <div>Password:</div>
  </div>
</section>
```